# Clearing cookies between selenium HTML tests?

Tags: cookies, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I'm running my HTML tests as such with selenium-server 2.2:
`java -jar /var/lib/selenium/selenium-server.jar -ensureCleanSession -htmlSuite *firefox http://$HOST ./test/selenium/html/TestSuite.html ./target/selenium/html/TestSuiteResults.html`

For some reason, I can't seem to get cookies to clear between individual tests in a test suite. Is there anything I can do to clear cookies between tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I am over-simplifying, but if you are aware of the domain in which your tests are running (and in turn, need to clear the cookies off them), you could use `selenium.deleteAllVisibleCookies();` as your final and initial test condition, between iterations.

Comment: How do I do this with HTML tests? Selenium RC tests aren't the issue here.

Comment: Ah, there's a command you can issue. I wish there was a way I didn't need to add this to every test.

Comment: You should be able to "open" the domain, and then simply run <td>deleteAllVisibleCookies</td>. Perhaps, you can add this as a 'clean-up' between each test in your suite.

Comment: How do I specify this as a global cleanup? Are you suggesting I add a "test" after each real test that does nothing but delete cookies?

Comment: Again, with the IDE, your options are limited - so, YES (to the best of my knowledge). With RC, on the other hand a repeated call to simple routine can suffice. Either way, depending on the number of domains that need to be cleared out, it should be two extra lines of code, either at the start or end of every test.